Visual studio code giving error for correct code
I have a pretty simple project and the specific line in question is the following:
    static final Locale defaultLocale = Locale.of("en", "US");

And vscode gives the following code
The method of(String, String) is undefined for the type LocaleJava(67108964)


Its worth mentioning that i can compile this code with gradle, now i thought maybe its a cache thing so i decided to switch to maven instead and i got the same error.
Any ideas? this error is driving me crazy.
Other editors like Intellij dont give this error

Locale.of(String, String) first appeared in Java 19...either you are pointing to a previous version or you are specifying the source to be of a previous version...Gradle compiler settings might be different and thats why it compiles without error

@PerdiEstaquel thnx mate i had actually done that before but as i was playing around i found that my vscode java runtime was set to java 17

Java 19+
The convenient static factory methods Locale.of were added to Java 19. You appear to be compiling for an earlier version of Java.

By the way, if using Visual Studio Code, consider: Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code

this method was added in Java19. So if your Java version is lower than it, it may not work. You can do this by installing the new version. Or use the constructor to see if the problem can be solved. It's like thisLocale locale=new Locale("en","US");
